# Can this DNS setup ever work?

Tags: networking, dns

First, an anecdote involving docker, which is incidental to this question:  I followed the procedure in [Skydock - Automagic Service Discovery for Docker](https://github.com/crosbymichael/skydock), which went well.  Now I have a DNS server listening on `172.17.42.1` that contains an entry for the host `redis1.redis.dev.docker` having IP `172.17.0.4`:

```
$ dig @172.17.42.1 redis1.redis.dev.docker

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-P2-RedHat-9.9.4-12.P2.fc20 <<>> @172.17.42.1 redis1.redis.dev.docker
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 51671
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;redis1.redis.dev.docker.       IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
redis1.redis.dev.docker. 29     IN      A       172.17.0.4

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 172.17.42.1#53(172.17.42.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Nov 05 21:04:01 EST 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 80
```

So the DNS service is working, right?  Okay, so I added the DNS server to my network interface script and I applied the changes:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search fghijk.local
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 172.17.42.1
```

However, when I `dig` without specifying the DNS server IP address as shown above, it seems that `192.168.0.1` is the only DNS server being consulted.

Now, maybe I'm doing something wrong, but my actual question is:

When should the secondary DNS server showing in my `/etc/resolv.conf` be consulted? **Is it only when the primary is down?**  My uneducated guess was that if the primary nameserver cannot answer the query, the secondary DNS server would be consulted.  **Is this guess just plain wrong?**  Does this behaviour change by operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secondary server in /etc/resolv.conf will only be used if the primary times out and does not provide a response at all - your guess is pretty much spot on.

This would appear true for all versions of Linux I am aware of, including embedded ones.  I'd imagine its true of other OS's as well.